# Can you use trading to build a wonder in 7 Wonders Duel?

Tags: 7-wonders-duel

In 7 Wonders Duel, one routinely purchases resources from the bank to build a Building. This is covered by these two rules:

> Resource Cost
>
> Some cards have a resource cost.
>   To construct them, you must produce the corresponding resources AND/OR buy 
>   them from the bank via the trading rules....

and

> Trading
>
> Often, you will want to construct a Building while you’re missing one or more 
>   required resources. In that case, you can always purchase the missing resources 
>   from the bank....

**EDIT** (to add a rules statement regarding a comment):

The first sentence of the **Overview & Object of the Game** section

> In 7 Wonders Duel, each player is leading a civilization and will construct Buildings and Wonders. All of the Buildings constructed by a player together with their Wonders are called a "city". ... Each Age card represents a Building.

Then in the **Game Elements ** section, the **Guild and Age cards** subsection:

> In 7 Wonders Duel, all of the Age and Guild cards represent Buildings. The Building cards all consist of a name, and effect and a construction cost.

Wonders are described in a separate subsection:

> Each large card represents a Wonder from the Age of Antiquity. Each Wonder consists of a name, a construction cost, and an effect.

So, the rules are very clear in distinguishing between a Wonder and a Building in the definitions of the Game Elements.
 (end of **EDIT**)

Notice that the Trading specifically mentions Buildings and not Wonders. Is it the proper interpretation that Wonders cannot be built by Trading resources with the bank since Wonders aren't stated in this rule? Or is it allowed?

(For comparison, in regular 7 Wonders, the group I play with routinely purchase resources from neighbors in order to build Wonders.)

Comment: I think it would be tricky to say a wonder is not a building.   The rules also never refer to anything as 'building cards'   The decks are called called Age and Guild cards (page 3)   if your interpretation were correct then a "guild' couldn't be constructed with resources from trading either.   I agree with answer below.   It would be unusual for this to not be clarified with a specific example in the rules if you couldn't buy missing resources for wonders.

Comment: @MildlyPerilous See my edit in my question. Wonders are not the same as Buildings as described in the rules.

Comment: I get what your saying but I'd hope if such a distinction was to be made that would be clarified in rules.   To be honest reading your interpretation I've been reading the rules over and over today as you had got my thinking.  However I've found online clarification from the designer which I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @MildlyPerilous I look forward to the clarification. As currently written, the designer made a clear distinction between Buildings and Wonders.  If he wishes to modify the Trading rules he should publish that.

Comment: Honestly it kind of ruins the game if you came just buy all the resources for the wonders, especially if you can buy a wonder with a additional turn play, and buy then next wonder with the next turn and so on....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out this same questions has been asked on BGG.  Thankfully the designer Bruno Cathala has responded to this question clear "just to confirm: yes you can !".

I can see from the question that a stretch it could be interpreted that Wonders are not buildings by wording of rules but the designer has clarified that trading is allowed for wonder construction.

[BGG rules forum link.](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1472554/can-you-trade-build-wonders)

Comment: Great detective work!  I hope the publisher will modify the rules to eliminate the confusion because often rules are very specific, and capitalizing Building and Wonder makes them specific categories that shouldn't be mixed, plus the very specific and separate listing in Game Elements.

Answer (score 3):

I can't link to a rule book right now ... However ...

The two rules you quoted are part of the section of the rule book entitled "Constructing in 7 Wonders Duel" (page 8).

On Page 10, it lists your options for a turn:

- Construct a Building
- Construct a Wonder

From this, I would conclude that trading (an element of Constructing) is allowed when Constructing a Wonder.

Comment: link to rules  http://www.7wondersduel.com/files/rules/7-Wonders-Duel-Rules-US.pdf

Comment: @hymie The first sentence on page 8 is "Throughout the game you will construct Buildings and Wonders. Most of the Buildings have a resource cost....The Wonders all have resource cost."  Buildings and Wonders are considered to be distinct and separate categories by this and other statements (see my edit to my question).  The section on Trading mentions **only** Buildings, not Wonders. On page 10, the construction only mentions paying the costs of Buildings and Wonders, but is neutral on the Trading issue. The Trading subsection back on page 8 would control that.